# Creating a Calendar table without recursion

Tags: sql-server

I want to create a Calendar Table without using the recursion as I have prepared earlier. How can I achieve this task. All the required columns are mentioned in code below and few other details in  code comments.
...........................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................

```
DECLARE @StartDate  date = '20200101'
DECLARE @CutoffDate date = GETDATE()

;WITH seq(n) AS 
(
  SELECT 0 UNION ALL SELECT n + 1 FROM seq
  WHERE n < DATEDIFF(DAY, @StartDate, @CutoffDate)
),
d(d) AS 
(
  SELECT DATEADD(DAY, n, @StartDate) FROM seq
),
src AS      /*SOURCE TABLE WITH OBJECT DEFINITION*/
(
  SELECT
    TheDate         = CONVERT(date, d),
    TheDay          = DATEPART(DAY,       d),
    TheDayName      = DATENAME(WEEKDAY,   d),
    TheWeek         = DATEPART(WEEK,      d),
    TheDayOfWeek    = DATEPART(WEEKDAY,   d),
    TheMonth        = DATEPART(MONTH,     d),
    TheMonthName    = DATENAME(MONTH,     d),
    TheQuarter      = Concat('Q',DATEPART(Quarter,   d)),
    Financial_Year  = DATEPART(YEAR,      d),
    Financial_Quarter=Datepart(QUARTER,d),
    TheYear         = DATEPART(YEAR,      d),
    TheFirstOfMonth = DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(d), MONTH(d), 1),
    TheFirstOfFYear   = DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(d), 4, 1),
    TheFirstOfYear   = DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(d), 1, 1),
    TheLastOfYear   = DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(d), 12, 31),
    TheDayOfYear    = DATEPART(DAYOFYEAR, d)
  FROM d
),
Dimension AS
(
  SELECT
    TheDate, 
    TheDay,
    TheDayName,
    TheDayOfWeek,
    TheDayOfWeekInMonth = CONVERT(tinyint, ROW_NUMBER() OVER 
                            (PARTITION BY TheFirstOfMonth, TheDayOfWeek ORDER BY TheDate)),
    TheDayOfYear,
    TheWeek,
    TheFirstOfWeek      = DATEADD(DAY, 1 - TheDayOfWeek, TheDate),
    TheLastOfWeek       = DATEADD(DAY, 6, DATEADD(DAY, 1 - TheDayOfWeek, TheDate)),
    TheWeekOfMonth      = CONVERT(tinyint, DENSE_RANK() OVER 
                            (PARTITION BY TheYear, TheMonth ORDER BY TheWeek)),
    TheMonth,
    TheMonthName,
    TheFirstOfMonth,
    TheLastOfMonth      = MAX(TheDate) OVER (PARTITION BY TheYear, TheMonth),
    TheFirstOfNextMonth = DATEADD(MONTH, 1, TheFirstOfMonth),
    TheLastOfNextMonth  = DATEADD(DAY, -1, DATEADD(MONTH, 2, TheFirstOfMonth)),
    TheQuarter,
    TheFirstOfQuarter   = MIN(TheDate) OVER (PARTITION BY TheYear, TheQuarter),
    TheLastOfQuarter    = MAX(TheDate) OVER (PARTITION BY TheYear, TheQuarter),
    TheYear,
    TheFirstOfYear      = DATEFROMPARTS(TheYear, 1,  1),
    TheFirstOfFYear     = DATEFROMPARTS(TheYear, 4,  1),
    TheLastOfYear,
    MMYYYY              = CONVERT(char(2), CONVERT(char(8), TheDate, 101))
                          + CONVERT(char(4), TheYear),
                            

    Financial_Quarter   = Datepart(Quarter,DATEADD(MONTH, -3, TheFirstOfMonth)), /*Starting Financial Quarter from April*/
    Financial_Year      =CASE
                            WHEN Financial_Quarter = 1 THEN DATEPART(Year,Dateadd(Year,-1,TheFirstofYear)) ELSE THEYEAR END

  FROM src
)
SELECT * FROM Dimension
  ORDER BY TheDate
  OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0);
```

Comment: Use a Tally instead; that are *far* faster.

Answer (score 3):

As I mentioned in the comments, use a Tally. These are *significantly* faster than a rCTE as they aren't recursive. I use an inline tally here:

```sql
DECLARE @StartDate date = '20200101';
DECLARE @CutoffDate date = GETDATE();
/*
; is a terminator, not a "beginingator". It goes at the end of ALL your statements,
not at the start of statements that require the PREVIOUS statement to be properly terminated.
*/
WITH N AS 
    (SELECT N
     FROM (VALUES (NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL)) N(N)),
Tally AS
    (SELECT 0 AS I
     UNION ALL
     SELECT TOP (DATEDIFF(DAY, @StartDate, @CutoffDate))
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS I
     FROM N N1,N N2,N N3), --Up to 1000 rows. Add more cross joins for more rows
D AS
    (SELECT DATEADD(DAY, T.I, @StartDate) AS d
     FROM Tally T),
Src AS /*SOURCE TABLE WITH OBJECT DEFINITION*/
    (SELECT CONVERT(date, d) AS TheDate,
            DATEPART(DAY, d) AS TheDay,
            DATENAME(WEEKDAY, d) AS TheDayName,
            DATEPART(WEEK, d) AS TheWeek,
            DATEPART(WEEKDAY, d) AS TheDayOfWeek,
            DATEPART(MONTH, d) AS TheMonth,
            DATENAME(MONTH, d) AS TheMonthName,
            CONCAT('Q', DATEPART(QUARTER, d)) AS TheQuarter,
            DATEPART(YEAR, d) AS Financial_Year,
            DATEPART(QUARTER, d) AS Financial_Quarter,
            DATEPART(YEAR, d) AS TheYear,
            DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(d), MONTH(d), 1) AS TheFirstOfMonth,
            DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(d), 4, 1) AS TheFirstOfFYear,
            DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(d), 1, 1) AS TheFirstOfYear,
            DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(d), 12, 31) AS TheLastOfYear,
            DATEPART(DAYOFYEAR, d) AS TheDayOfYear
     FROM d),
Dimension AS
    (SELECT TheDate,
            TheDay,
            TheDayName,
            TheDayOfWeek,
            CONVERT(tinyint, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY TheFirstOfMonth, TheDayOfWeek ORDER BY TheDate)) AS TheDayOfWeekInMonth,
            TheDayOfYear,
            TheWeek,
            DATEADD(DAY, 1 - TheDayOfWeek, TheDate) AS TheFirstOfWeek,
            DATEADD(DAY, 6, DATEADD(DAY, 1 - TheDayOfWeek, TheDate)) AS TheLastOfWeek,
            CONVERT(tinyint, DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY TheYear, TheMonth ORDER BY TheWeek)) AS TheWeekOfMonth,
            TheMonth,
            TheMonthName,
            TheFirstOfMonth,
            MAX(TheDate) OVER (PARTITION BY TheYear, TheMonth) AS TheLastOfMonth,
            DATEADD(MONTH, 1, TheFirstOfMonth) AS TheFirstOfNextMonth,
            DATEADD(DAY, -1, DATEADD(MONTH, 2, TheFirstOfMonth)) AS TheLastOfNextMonth,
            TheQuarter,
            MIN(TheDate) OVER (PARTITION BY TheYear, TheQuarter) AS TheFirstOfQuarter,
            MAX(TheDate) OVER (PARTITION BY TheYear, TheQuarter) AS TheLastOfQuarter,
            TheYear,
            DATEFROMPARTS(TheYear, 1, 1) AS TheFirstOfYear,
            DATEFROMPARTS(TheYear, 4, 1) AS TheFirstOfFYear,
            TheLastOfYear,
            CONVERT(char(2), CONVERT(char(8), TheDate, 101)) + CONVERT(char(4), TheYear) AS MMYYYY,
            DATEPART(QUARTER, DATEADD(MONTH, -3, TheFirstOfMonth)) AS Financial_Quarter, /*Starting Financial Quarter from April*/
            CASE
                 WHEN Financial_Quarter = 1 THEN DATEPART(YEAR, DATEADD(YEAR, -1, TheFirstOfYear))
                 ELSE TheYear
            END AS Financial_Year
     FROM src)
SELECT *
FROM Dimension
ORDER BY TheDate;
```

Comment: Great approach! Didn't know tallys yet, so learnt something new - thanks!

Comment: @Tyron78, also consider materializing a tally utility table for future use. See [this article](https://www.dbdelta.com/calendar-table-and-datetime-functions/) for example scripts for both a tally and calendar table which includes many US holidays.

Comment: @Larnu can you explain me little bit more how this tally functions and why you have taken nulls in start in select statement.

Comment: The `NULL`s are just placeholders, @MuskMelon , they could be any (constant) value; `0`, `1`, `'A literal string'`. I just personally tend to use `NULL`. As for what it's doing, it's actually quite simple, it takes the `NULL` values and then cross joins them to themslves; each `CROSS JOIN` increases the number of rows by a factor or 10. The the `Tally` then gives each of those rows a number (1+) and adds `0` at the start. The `TOP` limites the number of rows returned. Then it just uses those numbers and adds them to your start date, giving you all the dates you need.

Comment: @MuskMelon The `(NULL)` is just to generate a row for the row-numbering later, the value itself is not used. See https://sqlperformance.com/2021/01/t-sql-queries/number-series-solutions-1